# How to trigger shell script in Unix Server using PSCP Commands?

Tags: batch-file, unix, cmd, putty, pscp

I can move my input file to Unix Server Location with the commands mentioned in below link.

https://www.networkworld.com/article/3269189/sharing-files-between-linux-and-windows.html

After placing the file is it possible to trigger shell script using PSCP commands?

In 2019 we usually trigger 5 Shellscripts by Batch Script. That executed all the 5 one by one. But from 2020 batch script triggered all the 5 shell scripts at a time and all shell script jobs are failed. So I want to by PSCP commands instead of Command Prompt Commands to trigger shell scripts one by one in Unix Server.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl But I need run the shell script which is in Unix Server Path. Not on Windows Path.

Comment: Of course, that's what it does.